# Is there a concurrent sessions limit per user in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

A user can simultaneously have multiple sessions open using the same login credentials when authenticating via AWS Cognito.

Is there any limit on how many sessions a single user can have open at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by their very nature the JWTs provided by cognito are stateless and are not a replacement for sessions. If you want to limit the number active tokens you'll have to build it into your authorization check.

Comment: How? Is there a way to limit number of active sessions from the same user? the idea i had was to define a custom attribute as a counter and configure a pre authentication trigger to signout, if next time the same user tries to sign in when the counter reaches 3. But i dont know how to implement it? And how do i use the custom attribute i created in my backend code? Please do help. It is very much appreciated

Comment: @Srs Leave Cognito strictly as an authentication provider as it kind of stinks as an authorization provider. There are many ways you might want to handle it but at it's most basic do the the following; use the ID token to make a request to your own resource `GET /sessions` and either return a session token tied to the user, or return an error if the user has exhausted his session limit (you can handle it in other ways). The session tokens you generate should be stored and checked in authorization middleware to protect your other resources.

Comment: In the solution you proposed, you mentioned to return an error if the user has exhausted his session limit but how would i know if he exceded his limit? How do i set that limit to a maximum of 3 concurrent sessions for each unique user? The issue i am experiencing is to figure out a way to set the max concurrent sessions of every unique user to 3 and signout if he exceeds that.

Comment: Count the stored user sessions attached to your user. Don't sign the user out, just require the session token and ID token to access resources.

Comment: How do i count? i am not storing the sessions in any database and do you have any relavant code? Thanks

Comment: "The session tokens you generate should be stored and checked" DynamoDB would work for this. I'm not gonna implement it for you. I've outlined what approach you can take. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Storing the sessions in Dynamo Db or any DB isnt in scope of the project i am working on. we are using aws cognito for authentication and authorization and aws s3 to store files. Thats why trying to figure out a workaround.